# Getting Location form AD using HostingEnvironment.Impersonate()

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, active-directory

So I can get the 
Display name using the below method but I can't find the physicaldeliveryofficename of that result in AD. A side note is this method returns all matching and not just users so that could be part of the problem but I don't know how to refine the search to just users.

```
try
        {

            using (HostingEnvironment.Impersonate())
            {
                using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "********"))
                {
                    UserPrincipal qbeUser = new UserPrincipal(context);
                    qbeUser.GivenName = search.letters;
                    using (var searcher = new PrincipalSearcher(qbeUser))
                    {
                        foreach (var result in searcher.FindAll())
                        {
                            list.Add(result.Name);

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            return e.ToString();
        }
```

Comment: Well your problem is not that clear. But assuming that you want a `refined search`, you should see Robert Harvey's answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2128747/5588347).

Comment: @AshishSrivastava I'm trying to get physicaldeliveryofficename field form the result object.

Comment: Have you tried `result.PhysicalDeliveryOfficeName`?

Comment: said its not defined

Comment: You need yo get from a Principal to one of the types that has the attribute, see [Physical-Delivery-Office-Name attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679117(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/1788786/19308.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the code from [Per Noalt's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1788786/19308).  You need to get at the underlying type, like so:

`var directoryEntry = result.GetUnderlyingObject() as DirectoryEntry;
 directoryEntry.Properties["PhysicalDeliveryOfficeName"].Value`

**Warning:** the above code does not verify the cast, nor that the property exists on the object, and does no null checking.